# Discord.js bot command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

After I specify a person and use the command, I want the bot to say something to that person. I'm new to these jobs. I need your help.

example:

```
${prefix}warn @user123
Bot : @user123 you were warned
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this :

First, you have to set a const like 
`const user = message.mentions.users.first()`
It will set user to the user you mention

After your command, you can put
`` message.channel.send(`${user} you were warned`) ``

Comment: I prepared it to the best of my knowledge. But that wasn`t work.

code: const user = message.mentions.users.first()
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "warn" `<@${user.id}>`) {
        message.channel.send(`<@${user.id}> you were warned`)
 }   Can you fix this?

Comment: That's because it isn't a real warn command.

Here's my personnal warn command, just note that I use the v12.1.1 of Discord.JS
```let toWarn = message.mentions.members.first();
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + toWarn) {
              message.channel.send(`<@${toWarn}> were warned`);
 });```

Comment: @blour I just edited the answer, using `user` in a string will automatically make the bot mention that user, you do not need to use `<@${user.id}>`.

Other than that, please be more clear about your issues since "that wasn't work" doesn't say what's wrong